# Access image without upload

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a way to load image from an input type="file" on a page without uploading it to the server? can this process be handled by copying the image into a location where the script has access to it?

It is not import if it load after a refresh.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't access the local file (the client machine) system with JavaScript. You can get the value of the input file box but it will be useless.
You will have to use something else, Flash/Silverlight, Java or ActiveX.